# Android - Launch notification from anywhere?

Tags: java, android, android-service

I'm coding on the android right now, and I have an Activity which starts and stops a Service. However, related to this whole application will be a non-android java application which runs in the background alongside this app. I need this separate activity to be able to launch a notification, but I don't know how to do this. I cannot create a static method in either my Activity or my Service since then I wouldn't be able to get the context. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!
NS

Comment: You can use getApplicationContext() in static methods.

Comment: I tried, but you can't:
"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext() from the type ContextWrapper."
Similarly for getBaseContext();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...a non-android java application
>   which runs in the background alongside
>   this app

Ummm...there is no real support in Android for "a non-android java application".

> I need this separate activity to be
>   able to launch a notification, but I
>   don't know how to do this.

If it is an `Activity`, just use `NotificationManager` -- `Activity` is a `Context`.

If it is "a non-android java application", rewrite it such that it is an `Activity` or `Service`.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, that's not the answer I was hoping for since I was hoping for more of a "this magical class does it for you" kind of answer, but you're right.